# knife data bag from file - show what changed

Tags: chef-infra, knife, databags

When uploading a data bag to chef client is it possible to see what has changed, or what the difference is between a local file and the server?

Comment: Try the "knife diff" command: See http://docs.opscode.com/knife_diff.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `knife diff` command.

Docs: http://docs.opscode.com/knife_diff.html

Answer (score 0):

To view what is currently on the server:

```
knife data bag show <name> <data bag id> --secret-file <path_to_key>
```

You can drop the secret-file portion if you're not encrypting your passwords. If you want to drop it out to a json file so you can do the diff yourself it's:

```
knife data bag show <name> <data bag id> --format json --secret-file <path_to_key> > /tmp/data_bag_contents.json
```